# iOS - MBProgressHUD bezelView to be transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, mbprogresshud

I am using MBProgressHUD and want to make the bezelView to br transparent.

```
import UIKit
import MBProgressHUD

class ProgressBarManager {
   func showProgressBar() {
    guard let testView = UIApplication.shared.windows.last else { return }        
    let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: testView, animated: true)

    hud.bezelView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    hud.bezelView.backgroundColor = .clear
    hud.backgroundView.style = .solidColor
    hud.backgroundView.color = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)

 }
}
```

Yet the bezelView still shows:

[image]

Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: Did you try hud.backgroundView.color =  UIColor.clear ?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR yes, that makes the whole background to clear and not like above a bit dimmer

Answer (score 0):

Add this line for your *hud* init code:

```
hud.bezelView.style = .solidColor
```

Answer (score 0):

After HUD init, set it up with:

```
hud.bezelView.style = .solidColor
hud.bezelView.color = .clear
```